# How to parse all instances of an event from a string using SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying to find an instance of '17' in a string.

For eg, it could exist as 10,11,12,17,217
or 17,11,34,23 or 117,18,17,10

117,217,320 is no match, only the ones with '17' in the string

I need to do this using Oracle SQL.
I was thinking of using regular expressions but did not know where to start.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this tagged `netezza` if you need this for Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `INSTRB` or `INSTRC`
see docs here http://psoug.org/reference/string_func.html

```
INSTRB(
STR1 VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,        -- test string
STR2 VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET STR1%CHARSET,  -- string to locate
POS  PLS_INTEGER := 1,                     -- position
NTH  POSITIVE := 1)                        -- occurrence number
RETURN PLS_INTEGER;
SELECT INSTRB('Dan Morgan', ' ', 1, 1) FROM DUAL;
```